# Redirection form Laravel/Inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

My problem is that when I try to redirect my Vuejs form from my controller, I get a modal that appears when I click the Analyse button, not a  web page. I think the problem is with my form, as I'm unfamiliar with VueJs and Inertia. So far, I haven't solved anything.

Here is the code for the analyse() function from ReliabilityController:

```
public function analyse()
{
    //On recupère
    $analyse = request('analyse');
    
    //On va chercher l'extension du fichier pour lancer le job
    $data = json_decode($analyse["payload"], true);

    //On désérialise la donnée et on obtient l'extension
    $extension = unserialize($data["data"]["command"]);

    JobReliabilityAnalyze::dispatch($analyse, $extension->getExtension());

    //On retourne vers la page d'import du fichier fani
    return redirect("/fiabilisation")->with("message", "Analyse terminée");
}
```

```
//ResolveAmbigious.vue form and function (
 <form @submit.prevent="submitAnalyse"  method="post">

            <input id="analyse" :value="prepareReliabilityAnalyze" type="hidden">
            <button  :class="{
                    'enedis-btn': true,
                    'enedis-btn-small': true,
                    'enedis-btn-off': !prepareReliabilityAnalyze.ready,
                }" :disabled="!prepareReliabilityAnalyze.ready"
            >Lancer l'analyse</button>
  </form>//not all the code on the page is present

<script>

const form  = reactive({
    analyse : prepareReliabilityAnalyze,
})
/*
Fonction qui envoit le formulaire à analyser
 */
function submitAnalyse(){
    router.post('/analyse',form);
    

}
</script>
```

I'd like it to redirect to the url /fiabilisation.
When I debug, I find this in console: This page is in compatibility mode (quirks). The layout may be affected. For standard mode, use ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On any other request inertia displays the result on modal.

To redirect on `InertiaJS` request, you need to return `to_route()`.

```
return to_route('users.index');
```

According to your code it would be:

```
public function analyse()
{
    //On recupère
    $analyse = request('analyse');
    
    //On va chercher l'extension du fichier pour lancer le job
    $data = json_decode($analyse["payload"], true);

    //On désérialise la donnée et on obtient l'extension
    $extension = unserialize($data["data"]["command"]);

    JobReliabilityAnalyze::dispatch($analyse, $extension->getExtension());

    //On retourne vers la page d'import du fichier fani
    return to_route("/fiabilisation")->with("message", "Analyse terminée");
}
```

For more in detail regarding Inertia redirect: https://inertiajs.com/redirects